# Multi language site not working on sub domain

Tags: localization

I have an odd situation on a multi-lingual site I am building. I have the site set up on my local dev server and it works fine switching between languages. I have now added the site to an external server to show the client on a subdomain so test-dev.mydomain.com. Everything is exactly the same and the config file has been set up to target this domain. However now switching to another language only brings up the English version of the site when navigating past the home page. Any ideas what is happening here? Could this be because it is sitting on a subdomain?

Config snippet:

```
'test-dev.mydomain.com' => array(
    'devMode' => 'true',
    'env' => 'dev',
    'environmentVariables' => array(
        'siteStore' => '/assets',
        'sitePath'  => 'http://test-dev.mydomain.com/',
    ),
    'siteUrl' => array(
        'en_gb' => 'http://test-dev.mydomain.com/',
        'de_de' => 'http://test-dev.mydomain.com/de/',
        'pl_pl' => 'http://test-dev.mydomain.com/pl/',
        ),
)
```

Comment: Still have issue with multi-lingual site on a sub-domain. Found another thread that suggested removing rewritebase in the htaccess file but doing this on a sub-domain breaks all internal pages. So how do I test this on a sub-domain?

Answer (score 1):

Ok after several weeks of head scratching. I worked out the solution. So hopefully this will help someone else.

Each locale has it's own folder on the root. So to enable you to view the pages on a subdomain you need to edit the .htaccess file within the locale folder and add a RewriteBase /fr or whatever the folder name of the locale you are targeting is.

This will then resolve the problem.

Hope this helps someone else.